# bash script doesn't wait for other processes to finish to print the duration

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to measure the time it takes for my processes to finish, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


SECONDS=0
launching some processes
process1
process2
process3

duration=$SECONDS
echo "Time: $duration"
```

however, it prints the `echo` immediately as the script runs, and then the other processes start running, so the time doesn't take into account the duration of the processes.
how can i make it wait until the process are finished and then print the duration?

### update

my processes are like this, here is an example:

```
$ROOT/transform --config=file1.xml --param2=value2 --param3=file3.xml $TARGET/input.xml > $TARGET/output2.xml
```

Comment: Don't you have a `&` at the end of your processes invocations? Because that would explicitly ask them to run in the background, which would explain why your script carries on printing the incorrect duration.

Comment: Looks like the processes are daemons. Can you be more specific? What exactly is `process1`, `process2` and `process3`?

Comment: i copy pasted an example from my script, please see the updated question. i have couple of those processes, which have their input output parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `time` command, like

```
shell> time my_shellscript.sh
```

It will do the job for you. [Here](https://www.lifewire.com/command-return-time-command-4054237)'s a website explaining it. Or the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) for additional info.

If you want to do it inside your shellscript anyway, you have to specify the PID of the process you're waiting on (or multiple).

```
#!/bin/bash

process1 &
PID_process1=$!
process2 &
PID_process2=$!

wait $PID_process1 $PID_process2
```

Comment: how can i know the PID of the process?

Comment: It's in the `$!` variable, which you store in your own variable if you want to wait for more than one process. Sorry, thought the code would be self explaining. But why don't you use `time` instead? It's much more convenient and you can do so much more with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `wait` before `echo` to wait for process to end. like this :

```
wait
echo "Time: $duration'
```

Comment: The assignment of `duration` should be after the `wait`: 
`wait; duration=$SECONDS; echo "Time: $duration"`